# Returns both a value and a reference to its internal field in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am trying to return an object together with a reference to its internal body, e.g.

```rust
struct S {
    i: i8,
}

fn ret_ref() -> (S, &i8) {
    let s = S{i: 3};
    (s, &s.i)
}
```

And the lifetime checker recognized that `&i8` might have a shorter lifetime than the original value. now if I return `s` together, is there a way to extend the lifetime of the reference?

Comment: Your returned tuple is equivalent to a struct like in this: [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)